# Azure ARM policy deployment deny specific sku.name

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy, azure-bicep

I am extremely confused about arm deployment for policies, and I hope somebody can help me to solve this issue.

I would like to have in place a policy which denies the database deployment based on their Sku.name.

Right noe I would like to allow the creation of databases that they are `standard` or `Basic`, and Deny all the other sku.

I have this `json` configuration, but it works partially.

```
{
    "properties": {
      "displayName": "Not allowed resource types",
      "policyType": "BuiltIn",
      "mode": "All",
      "description": "This policy enables you to specify the resource types that your organization cannot deploy.",
      "parameters": {
        "listOfAllowedSKUs": {
          "type": "Array",
          "metadata": {
            "description": "The list of resource types that cannot be deployed.",
            "displayName": "Not allowed resource types",
            "strongType": "resourceTypes"
          }
        }
      },
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "field": "type",
          "in": "[parameters('listOfAllowedSKUs')]"
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "Deny"
        }
      }
    },
    "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/6c112d4e-5bc7-47ae-a041-ea2d9dccd749",
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
    "name": "6c112d4e-5bc7-47ae-a041-ea2d9dccd749"
  }
```

parameters:

```
{
    "listOfAllowedSKUs": {
    "type": "Array",
    "allowedValues": [
      "Standard",
      "Basic"
    ],
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "Allowed SKUs",
      "description": "The list of SKUs that can be specified for databases."
    }
  }
}
```

and the rules:

```
{
    "if": {
        "not": {
          "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/sku.name",
            "in": "[parameters('listOfAllowedSKUs')]"
          }
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
}
```

When I Deploy this policy, I can deploy only the Basic Sku, while all the other, Standard included, are denied.

How can I allow to create both `Basic` and `Standard`?

Thank you so much to whoever will spend his precious time to help me understand this.

Comment: You need to filter on the `sku.tier`. For basic, name and tier are the same but for standard, tier = standard and name can be S1, S2 etc....

Comment: Yes I just managed to make it work using `Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/sku.tier` and I was able to create only standard and Basic. If you want to post it as an answer I will vote it. Just a basic question, where I can find all the specification for the resources, like `Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/sku.tier` etc? is there a documentation that I can read to understand what sub resource I can target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/databases?tabs=bicep#sku):

- sku tier: The tier or edition of the particular SKU, e.g. Basic, Premium.
- sku name: The name of the SKU, typically, a letter + Number code, e.g. P3.

So you would need to filter on the **sku tier** in you case.
For Basic, name and tier are the same.
For Standard, tier is Standard but name can be S1...S12

```json
{
    "if": {
        "not": {
          "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/sku.tier",
            "in": "[parameters('listOfAllowedSKUs')]"
          }
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
}
```